# facebook Audience Network can showing banner ads

Tags: android, facebook

I follow this steps here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/banner

and add the code to :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        RelativeLayout adViewContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.adViewContainer);
        adView = new AdView(this, "1670296059907230_1681918298745006", AdSize.BANNER_320_50);
        adViewContainer.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd();
```

It shows this line 2 lines with something wrong:

```
adView = new AdView(this, "1670296059907230_1681918298745006", AdSize.BANNER_320_50);
    adViewContainer.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd();
```